# Slow loading in edit mode - only on some pages Drupal 7.22

Tags: performance

On editing some pages, there's a 20 second wait, and on others it's only 1-2 seconds. Both are the same content types.

I seem to always get the following error message:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in node_page_title() (line 2211 of /data/www/www.xxx.xx.xx/modules/node/node.module).
```

Comment: 20 second wait to load the edit form, or to save the edits?  Do you have [devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) installed? Check for slow queries there.  Have you looked at the network tab in Chrome DevTools to see if anything stands out?

Comment: Try https://drupal.org/project/xhprof to find out the function which takes more time.